# How to use pkgutil.walk_packages for a zipped package

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I find the modules in a zipped package without unzipping it first?

I am inspecting a package using [`pkgutil.walk_packages`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.walk_packages) and pulling out all the modules using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html).

```
for _, pkg, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(package.__path__):
    yield importlib.import_module(pkg)
```

This doesn't work when the package is zipped. `walk_packages` takes a path.

I can do it by first unzipping the package and using:

```
for _, pkg, _ in pkgutil.walk_packages(unzipped_package_path):
    yield importlib.import_module(pkg)
```

But I'd like to be able to do it without unzipping first.

`pkgutil.getdata` works with zipped packages, I was surprised `pkgutil.walk_packages` didn't work.

I was wondering whether I was missing something.

Also, I'm restricted to Python 2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Python 2.7.5. With urwid as an egg, which is just a .zip file, on PYTHONPATH:

```
>>> import pkgutil, urwid
>>> list(pkgutil.walk_packages(urwid.__path__))

[(<zipimporter object "urwid.egg/urwid/">,
  'canvas',
  False),
 (<zipimporter object "urwid.egg/urwid/">,
  'command_map',
  False),
 (<zipimporter object "urwid.egg/urwid/">,
  'compat',
  False),
...
```

But the package names are all relative to `urwid`. Use `importlib.import_module('urwid.canvas')` instead of `importlib.import_module('canvas')`. `pkgutil.walk_packages` will also accept a `prefix='urwid.'` keyword argument and prefix that text to the output names.

You should also pay attention to the third value `ispkg` from `walk_packages`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll look at this. I think I remember there being an issue with 2.7.0.